# Get values out of an object into properties of another class

Tags: c#, arrays, object

i have a gridview

```
INSEE1  Commune
------  -------
10002   AILLEVILLE
10003   BRUN
```

i have a script that return a list of object.

```
List<object> Temp = ASPxGridView_Insee.GetSelectedFieldValues("INSEE1");
```

my Temp is a list of object of INSSE1 that i have selected.

but now i add Commune also, so my script become:

```
List<object> Temp = ASPxGridView_Insee.GetSelectedFieldValues("INSEE1","Commune");
```

and my Temp is list of object of INSEE1 and Commune look at image:

[image]

how can i acces 10002 and AILLEVILLE ?

i have try with cast it of my Pers_INSEE class:

```
public class Pers_InseeZone
{
    string _Code_Insee;
    public string Code_Insee
    {
        get { return _Code_Insee; }
        set { _Code_Insee = value; }
    }

    string _Commune;
    public string Commune
    {
        get { return _Commune; }
        set { _Commune = value; }
    }
}

foreach (var oItem in Temp )
                {
Pers_InseeZone o = (Pers_InseeZone)oItem;

}
```

but I not work, I can not cast it.
I have tried like this:

```
foreach (var oItem in Temp )
{
    var myTempArray = oItem as IEnumerable;

    foreach (var oItem2 in myTempArray)
    { 
        string res= oItem2.ToString();
```

....

the value of `res = 10002`, but how can I get the value of AILEVILLE ?

the value of `Temp[0].GetType();` is:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you access with `typeof` to see what is the concrete class for `object` ? and later cast into the object

Comment: You get array of array of values. Simply use index to read second one: `oItem[1]`.

Comment: can you please do `Temp[0].GetType()` and post the result?

Comment: i post it as a picture

Comment: @Soft8Stev the last information is actually essential ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I thought so, so as already mentioned in the comments you have a array of objects inside each object so you need to cast first every object in your list into an array of objects: `object[]` then you can access each part. Here is an example that recreates your problem:

```
object[] array = new object[] {10002, "AILEEVILLE"};    
List<object> Temp = new List<object> {array};
```

[image]

And the solution:

```
// cast here so that the compiler knows that it can be indexed
object [] obj_array = Temp[0] as object[];

List<Pers_InseeZone> persList = new List<Pers_InseeZone>();

Pers_InseeZone p = new Pers_InseeZone()
{
    Code_Insee = obj_array[0].ToString(),
    Commune = obj_array[1].ToString()
};

persList.Add(p);
```

Applied to your code it would look something like this:

```
List<object> Temp = ASPxGridView_Insee.GetSelectedFieldValues("INSEE1","Commune");
List<Pers_InseeZone> persList = new List<Pers_InseeZone>();

foreach (object oItem in Temp )
{
    object [] obj_array = oItem as object[];

    Pers_InseeZone p = new Pers_InseeZone()
    {
        Code_Insee = obj_array[0].ToString(),
        Commune = obj_array[1].ToString()
    };

    persList.Add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is down to the fact your `class` doesn't match the same structure as the data you are getting, so it can't be cast into it.

Instead why don't you just iterate over the results and build a new instance of the class?

```
var tempList = new List<Pers_InseeZone>();
foreach (var oItem in Temp)
{
    tempList.Add(new Pers_InseeZone(oItem[0], oItem[1]));
}
```

You will need to add a constructor to your `Pers_InseeZone` class, and assign the variables there.

Comment: thanks, but i can not indexed oItem, because is an object.